# deploying django application on Apache using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've got some problems with deploying Django application on Apache HTTP server with mod_wsgi. I've added information to httpd.conf (WSGIScriptAlias) which indicate file wsgi.py with test content:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

and when I run it everything seems to be OK, bacause I can see 'Hello world!'. But when I change file wsgi.py to this:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've got:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

wsgi.py file is in the same directory as settings.py file... (and all my app is in the subdirectory: mydomain/public_html/hc/hc/hc/settings.py - hc is the name of my app)

What can be wrong? What should I do, to make my app work? how to find out which thing causes error?

Comment: Plus you should post the error from the Apache log (probably /var/httpd/error.log).

Comment: Definitely an Apache config issue. It may be a permissions problem. Also, take a look at [this similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584713/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-handlers-wsgi-in-install-django-mod-wsg).

Comment: post your apache configuration file

Comment: anyone from my previous topic didn't help me, so i can't match anything

Comment: i've got no permission to access apache configuration file - i've got django hosting and i can only add alias to httpd.conf (which is added by admin) - so configuration of apache is probably good, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
sys.path.append('path_to_python_dir')
sys.path.append('path_to_project')
```

add these lines to your wsgi.py file .

Issues in  settings.py also causes 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

i've solve my problem on my own
added this help me (after imports):

```
sys.path.append('path_to_project')
sys.path.append('path_to_wsgi_py_file')
```